# Matching a number with numbers in a list variable

Tags: bash, if-statement, for-loop

What am I doing wrong in this for-loop? I have the variable `$gGID` which contain some numbers. I have another that uses the top number of the list which is the `$ONEGID` variable. I want to use `$ONEGID` be matched against the list in `$gGID` and if a match do something else continue.

```
echo $ONEGID

116899029375914044550
```

I collect whats in `$gGID` with

```
gGID=$(curl -A 'Mozilla/4.0' --silent "https://www.google.com/search?q=$Daniel%20Sandman%20plus.google.com" | grep -P -o '(?<=plus.google.com/)[^az/u]+(?=/)')
```

This is what `$gGID` gives me..

```
echo $gGID

116899029375914044550
116899029375914044550
116899029375914044550
108176814619778619437
108176814619778619437
108176814619778619437
105237212888595777019
105237212888595777019
105237212888595777019
```

This is the for-loop I use to match it.

```
for USERS in $gGID; do
    if [ "$USERS" = "$ONEGID" ]; then
        echo "More than one match"
    else
        echo "Just one match"
    fi
done
```

I have tried in multiple ways and not figured it out. I don't see what I am doing wrong. Could it be that the variable I stored in `$gGID` count as a single number and that is why?

Comment: What happens when you run it?  Why is it not working?

Comment: @TimPote It should give "More than one match" but gives "Just one match". It's like it doesn't go through the numbers one by one. "Just one match" is for when there isn't any match.

Comment: What's in your `$gGID`. These's no way to print `new line` without being quoted.

Comment: @kev Ohh... sorry, should have added that of course. `gGID=$(curl -A 'Mozilla/4.0' --silent "https://www.google.com/search?q=$Daniel%20Sandman%20plus.google.com" | grep -P -o '(?<=plus.google.com/)[^az/u]+(?=/)')`

Comment: Do you mean: `echo "$gGID"`? Without the quotation marks, the result will be one line.

Comment: Add some `echo "$USERS" | od` and `echo "$ONEGID" | od` in your `for...loop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not certain what you mean, why would you echo "just one match" when it does not match?  Anyway, is this what you mean?

```
#!/bin/bash

ONEGID=116899029375914044550  

gGID=\
"116899029375914044550 
116899029375914044550 
116899029375914044550 
108176814619778619437 
108176814619778619437 
108176814619778619437 
105237212888595777019 
105237212888595777019 
105237212888595777019"

matches=0

for USERS in $gGID; do 
    if [[ $USERS == $ONEGID ]]
    then 
        (( matches++ ))
    fi 
done 

if (( matches == 0 ))
then
    echo "no matches"
elif ((matches == 1 ))
then
    echo "Just one match"
else
    echo "$matches matches"
    echo "more than one match"
fi
```

(Tested before the question was changed to include curl - works with the curl as well)

Comment: Yes, this was the exact thing i was after. Sorry if my explanation was bad. I wanted two states.. If the curl match with just on user id or if the curl had many and then do things differently if that was the case.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're trying to do is get the number of matches, use `grep`. In particular, you should look at the `-c` (count), `-F` (plain text), and `-x` (full line) switches:

```
$ grep -cFx "$ONEGID" <<<"$gGID"
3
```

In fact, you can skip the `$gGID` variable altogether and use `curl` directly:

```
curl -A 'Mozilla/4.0' --silent "https://www.google.com/search?q=$Daniel%20Sandman%20plus.google.com" | grep -P -o '(?<=plus.google.com/)[^az/u]+(?=/)' \
    | grep -cFx "$ONEGID"
```

(split for readability)